# How to override Member's Avatars in BuddyPress

Tags: buddypress, avatar

I have tried everything to override the BP Avatar. Found about 5-6 different Google results that basically all point to the same solution:

```
function override_bp_member_avatar($url) {
    return get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/default_avatar.png';
}
add_filter('bp_core_fetch_avatar_no_grav', '__return_true'); // http://codex.buddypress.org/extending-buddypress/tips-tricks/
add_filter('bp_core_mysteryman_src', 'override_bp_member_avatar'); // http://www.buddyboss.com/instructions/
```

Yet it does not work.

Has anyone had success using a default Avatar for members?

Comment: The Simple Facebook Connect plugin replaces avatars with Facebook profile pictures. You might check out that plugin, specifically the `sfc-login.php` file to see how it's being done.

Answer (score 2):

The filters you cite are only for the default/fallback avatars. If you want to replace BP avatars altogether, the key filters are `bp_core_fetch_avatar` and `bp_core_fetch_avatar_url`. The latter filters the entire HTML avatar element, while the latter does just the URL.

How you do the filtering depends on how fancy you want to get. The `bp_core_fetch_avatar` passes along a lot of useful parameters, if you want to totally rebuild the avatar HTML: https://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/1.5.5/bp-core/bp-core-avatars.php#L297 Otherwise, for a quick fix, you could just `preg_replace()` the URL.

```
/**
 * This function returns your new avatar URL. You can put whatever logic in here you want
 */
function wpse_49216_my_new_avatar_url() {
    return 'http://example.com/avatar.jpg';
}
add_filter( 'bp_core_fetch_avatar_url', 'wpse_49216_my_new_avatar_url' );

function wpse_49216_filter_bp_avatar( $html ) {
    return preg_replace( '/src=".+?"/', 'src="' . wpse_49216_my_new_avatar_url() . '"', $html );
}
add_filter( 'bp_core_fetch_avatar', 'wpse_49216_filter_bp_avatar' );
```

EDIT: The above method will replace all avatars. If you only want to change the default/fallback avatar (for users who have not uploaded their own), try

```
/**
 * Disable Gravatar throughout BP
 */
add_filter( 'bp_core_fetch_avatar_no_grav', '__return_true' );

/**
 * Provide a global user avatar default
 */
function wpse_49216_my_new_default_avatar_url() {
    return 'http://example.com/avatar.jpg';
}
add_filter( 'bp_core_default_avatar_user', 'wpse_49216_my_new_default_avatar_url' );
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. When you first said "I have tried everything to override the BP Avatar" I figured you wanted to override all avatars. I have edited my answer with a proper method. As you note, it's a bad idea to change the core files, and in this case there are several filters there that make it unnecessary to do so.

Comment: what the hell  wpse_49216_my_new_default_avatar_url() this is not found in the source code.
@boone Gorges

Comment: This code did not work