# How to set the default avatar of buddypress avatar

Tags: functions, buddypress, avatar

I need a way to set the default avatar for buddypress's `bp_core_fetch_avatar`. Using the regular `get_avatar` you can just set the `$default` path but I can't find anyway to do it with buddypress's function. For instance, I use this function to get the full size avatar for a post author but adding `default => "mysite.com/default.png"` doesn't pass.

```
function fod_post_author_avatar() {
global $post;

if ( function_exists('bp_core_fetch_avatar') ) {
    echo apply_filters( 'bp_post_author_avatar', bp_core_fetch_avatar( array( 'item_id' => $post->post_author, 'type' => 'full', 'width' => "130px", 'height' => "130px", default => "http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/123/images/default-avatar.png" ) ) ); 
} else if ( function_exists('get_avatar') ) {
    get_avatar();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As @shanebp said:

> You can define the default avatar site-wide by using BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT

For this you can define the constant(s) `BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT` and/or `BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT_THUMB` inside the [`bp-custom.php`](http://codex.buddypress.org/plugindev/bp-custom-php/) as described at the buddypress codex page [Customizing BuddyPress Avatars](http://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/guides/customizing-buddypress-avatars/#how-to-change-the-default-buddypress-avatar), for example like this:

**Code:**

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();  
$url_default_avatar = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/defaults/buddypress/default-member-avatar.png';  
$url_default_avatar_thumb = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/defaults/buddypress/default-member-avatar-thumb.png';  
define ( 'BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT', $url_default_avatar );  
define ( 'BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT_THUMB', $url_default_avatar_thumb );
```

Another method of setting a default avatar has been described at this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/49221/22534) to a (very) similar question. For this the use of gravatar gets disabled, after that you can easily change the default (member) avatar. A plus with this method is that the default group avatar can be changed easily too - that's the reasons, otherwise it would be redundant, I'm replicating this method, because the group avatar isn't part of the answer I've referenced. That said, the use of this method would for example be like this:

**Code:**

```
// disable gravatar  
add_filter( 'bp_core_fetch_avatar_no_grav', '__return_true' );

// default member avatar  
function wpse_54037_default_avatar_avatar() {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    return $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/defaults/buddypress/default-member-avatar.png';
}
add_filter( 'bp_core_default_avatar_user', 'wpse_54037_default_avatar_avatar' );

// default group avatar
function wpse_54037_default_group_avatar() {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    return $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/defaults/buddypress/default-group-avatar.png';
}
add_filter( 'bp_core_default_avatar_group', 'wpse_54037_default_group_avatar' );
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need a way to set the default avatar for buddypress's bp_core_fetch_avatar.

Why?

> adding default => "mysite.com/default.png" doesn't pass

There is no 'default' option in that BP function
http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/buddypress/nav.html?bp-core/bp-core-avatars.php.source.html#l78

You can define the default avatar site-wide by using BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT